# Running Airport Utility under WINE?

Tags: wine, apple

I can't get APUtil.exe running under wine. I installed [version 5.5.3](http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1391) under wine-1.5.12. I'm on Ubuntu 12.04. When I try to run it, here's what I get:

```
$ wine APUtil.exe 
fixme:heap:HeapSetInformation (nil) 1 (nil) 0
fixme:advapi:RegisterEventSourceW ((null),L"Bonjour Service"): stub
fixme:winsock:WSAIoctl WS_SIO_UDP_CONNRESET stub
fixme:winsock:WSAIoctl -> SIO_ADDRESS_LIST_CHANGE request: stub
fixme:iphlpapi:CreateIpForwardEntry (pRoute 0x78e944): stub
fixme:service:EnumServicesStatusW resume handle not supported
fixme:service:EnumServicesStatusW resume handle not supported
fixme:advapi:ReportEventA (0xcafe4242,0x0004,0x0000,0x00000064,(nil),0x0001,0x00000000,0x78e5a8,(nil)): stub
fixme:advapi:ReportEventW (0xcafe4242,0x0004,0x0000,0x00000064,(nil),0x0001,0x00000000,0x12e840,(nil)): stub
fixme:netapi32:NetGetJoinInformation Semi-stub (null) 0x78e664 0x78e66c
fixme:winsock:WSAIoctl WS_SIO_UDP_CONNRESET stub
err:module:import_dll Loading library dnssd.dll (which is needed by L"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\AirPort\\APUtil.exe") failed (error c000007b).
err:module:LdrInitializeThunk Main exe initialization for L"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\AirPort\\APUtil.exe" failed, status c0000135
fixme:advapi:ReportEventA (0xcafe4242,0x0004,0x0000,0x00000064,(nil),0x0001,0x00000000,0x78e5a4,(nil)): stub
fixme:advapi:ReportEventW (0xcafe4242,0x0004,0x0000,0x00000064,(nil),0x0001,0x00000000,0x12e1a8,(nil)): stub
```

I haven't used wine since about 2001.

Incidentally, [version 5.6.1](http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1547) is available, but it complains that it requires Windows 7 SP1.

Answer (score 2):

You can try Airport Utility 5.4.2.
It worked for me with wine1.5 on 12.04 ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me with version 5.6.1: Make sure your wine configured as Windows 7 (winecfg). Copy dnssd.dll from Windows 7 or find it on the Internet. Place it at the Airport Utility directory under .wine. Done.